# Adding a smaller array to a part of a bigger array?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a large array of dimension 64x4x45x14.

I initialize it to all zeros as:

```
Main = zeros(64,4,45,14);
```

I have another array S_avg of dimension 45x14 ;

If I do something like this, why does Matlab give an error?

```
Main(chan_no,level,:,:) = Main(chan_no,level,:,:) + S_avg ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reshape the matrix S_avg first, try this here

```
Main(chan_no,level,:,:) = Main(chan_no,level,:,:) + reshape(S_avg, 1, 1, size(S_avg, 1), size(S_avg, 2)) ;
```

or if you know the size of S_avg for sure

```
Main(chan_no,level,:,:) = Main(chan_no,level,:,:) + reshape(S_avg, 1, 1, 45, 14) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the singleton dimensions with `squeeze`.

Use this code instead,

```
Main(chan_no,level,:,:) = squeeze(Main(chan_no,level,:,:)) + S_avg ;
```

The reason is that,

```
size(Main(chan_no,level,:,:)) = 1   1   45   14
```

While,

```
size(S_avg) = 45   14
```

so you get a *dimension mismatch error*.